# Accessing Async Property in Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am trying to bring up a simple .NET Core 2.0 Web Application with Razor pages.  The page is connected to an equally simple Core 2.0 Web API. I have a simple class:

```
public class About : PageModel
{
    private ServiceProxy serviceProxy;

    public About(ServiceProxy serviceProxy)
    {
        this.serviceProxy = serviceProxy;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Values { get; set; }

    public async void OnGetAsync()
    {
        this.Values = await this.serviceProxy.GetValuesAsync();
    }
}
```

And the page is also simple:

```
@page
@model About
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<h3>@Model.Message</h3>
@foreach (var product in @Model.Values)
{
    <p>@product.Name</p>
}
```

However, the page displays before the `OnGetAsync()` method can populate the 'Values' list. This seems like such a common operation, but I can't find any discussion of it (I've also tried iterating over an async 'GetValues()' method).

How are CSHTML pages supposed to interact with a Web API that may take a few seconds to return results?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is because of the `async void`, which is basically a fire and forget, and should be avoided. The page will load before the function has time to complete as they will be executing in parallel.

Change the signature to `async Task` so that the Page can await the action to complete.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync() {
    this.Values = await this.serviceProxy.GetValuesAsync();
    return Page();
}
```

Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio)